# What does this git diff-index --quiet HEAD --; mean?

Tags: git

I found the following command in a shell script:

```
 git diff-index --quiet HEAD --;
```

What does this command mean/do?

Comment: Try running `git help diff-index`.

Answer (score 18):

It can be used to help determine whether there are any changes in a working tree by comparing your working tree to the `HEAD` revision.  The `--quiet` means to silence the output and alter the exit code based on whether the tree is modified (exits with 1) or is not modified (exits with 0).  The `--` is used to separate paths from the rest of the argument.  This helps Git know that `HEAD` is actually the name of a treeish, rather than confuse it with the name of a file should a file called `HEAD` exist in your tree.

The short form: if the script is using `set -e`, then the script will exit with an error if your working tree has changes in it.

Comment: Why not just use `git diff --quiet`, though?

Comment: In Git, there's a difference between commands meant for the end user (porcelain) and for scripts (plumbing).  `git diff` is a porcelain command whereas `git diff-index` is plumbing.  You could probably get by with using `git diff` here if you really wanted to though.

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley Here's a list of [plumbing commands](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html#_low_level_commands_plumbing), just for reference.

Comment: Believe me, [I know about Git's plumbing commands](https://github.com/c9/open-in-c9-extension/pull/11#issuecomment-86158657). What I'm trying to ascertain is, is there a reason that a script would use `git diff-index --quiet HEAD --` instead of `git diff --quiet`, other than a predilection for plumbing over porcelain? (The latter was added in [Git 1.5.1](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89815cab95268e8f0f58142b848ac4cd5e9cbdcb/Documentation/RelNotes-1.5.1.txt), so they're both nearly as old as Git itself.)

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley Outside of `git diff-index` being a plumbing command, no I don't know of any other reason to chose it over `git diff` in this case.  There's no performance benefit or the like since `git diff` essentially calls `git diff-index` under the hood in this case.